# Problem with my first Spring application - cant see controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, controller

I'm studying back end and i'm following many guides on the web.
I've done this application, when i do the get call on postman on /api/anagrafica this error appears:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-12-21T21:59:07.341+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/api/anagrafica"
}
```

following in order the code of model,service,controller,repository and the log console when i do the get..

MODEL:

```
@Table(name = "anagrafica")

@Entity
public class Anagrafica {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long Id;
    private String nome;

    public long getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Anagrafica(long id, String nome) {
        Id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class AnagraficaService {
    @Autowired
    private IAnagraficaRepository anagRepository;


    public Iterable<Anagrafica> getAll(){
        return anagRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Optional<Anagrafica> getById(Long id){
        return anagRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public Anagrafica create(Anagrafica anag){
       return anagRepository.save(anag);
    }

    public Optional<Anagrafica> update(Long id,Anagrafica anag){
        Optional<Anagrafica> anagr= anagRepository.findById(id);
        if(anagr.isEmpty()){
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        anagr.get().setNome(anag.getNome());
        anagRepository.save(anagr.get());
        return anagr;

    }

    public String delete (Long id){
        Optional<Anagrafica> anagr= anagRepository.findById(id);
        if(anagr.isEmpty()){
            return "Non si può cancellare";
        }
        anagRepository.delete(anagr.get());
        return "Cancellato";
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class AnagraficaController {
    @Autowired
    private AnagraficaService anagService;
    
    public AnagraficaController(){

    }
    @GetMapping("/api/anagrafica")
    public Iterable<Anagrafica> getAll(){
        System.out.println("Calling getAll() method in AnagraficaController");
        return anagService.getAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/anagrafica/{id}")
    public Anagrafica getById(@PathVariable  Long id){
       Optional<Anagrafica> anagr= anagService.getById(id);
       if(anagr.isEmpty()){
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,"item not found");

        }
        return anagr.get();
    }
    @PostMapping("/api/anagrafica")
    public Anagrafica create(@RequestBody Anagrafica anag){

        return anagService.create(anag);
    }
    @PutMapping("/api/anagrafica/{id}")
    public Optional<Anagrafica> update(Long id,@RequestBody Anagrafica anag){

        return anagService.update(id,anag);

    }

    @DeleteMapping("/api/anagrafica/{id}")
    public String delete (Long id){
        return anagService.delete(id);
    }

}
```

repository:

```
@Repository
public interface IAnagraficaRepository extends CrudRepository<Anagrafica, Long> {
   
}
```

THIS IS WHAT APPEARS ON CONSOLE WHEN I DO THE GET.

```
`2023-12-21T23:04:21.583+01:00 DEBUG 18012 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/api/anagrafica", parameters={}
2023-12-21T23:04:21.584+01:00 DEBUG 18012 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-12-21T23:04:21.585+01:00 DEBUG 18012 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2023-12-21T23:04:21.585+01:00 DEBUG 18012 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource api/anagrafica.]
2023-12-21T23:04:21.585+01:00 DEBUG 18012 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2023-12-21T23:04:21.585+01:00 DEBUG 18012 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2023-12-21T23:04:21.586+01:00 DEBUG 18012 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2023-12-21T23:04:21.586+01:00 DEBUG 18012 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2023-12-21T23:04:21.586+01:00 DEBUG 18012 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Thu Dec 21 23:04:21 CET 2023, status=404, error=Not Found, path=/api/anagrafica}]
2023-12-21T23:04:21.587+01:00 DEBUG 18012 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

I expect that the api/anagrafica works.

Comment: Try to put `@RequestMapping` to the controller.

Comment: I resolved it, that was a dumb problem. I've put the main in a package outside the others package with inside the controllers,services ecc.. Sorry

Comment: Are you using MVC? If so, please check if the component scan configuration is correct.